# Ubuntu Server 20 does not boot when exfat external drive is connected

Tags: boot, exfat

Bought an 8TB WD My Book external drive to replace an existing hard drive. The drive is formatted as exfat as per the output of "sudo blkid | grep UUID=".
I am able to mount/unmount the drive without any issues and am able to access the contents of the drive.
My issue is that when I reboot the server, it does boot up with the drive connected (via usb). If I remove the drive and reboot, the server boots up. Connecting the external drive after boot up does not cause any issues.
Do I need to configure anything in order get my server boot up with the external drive connected?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to go into the BIOS and make sure the boot sequence has the drives sorted in the correct order. Since every BIOS is somewhat different, please refer to your BIOS manual for more information.

Comment: thanks @guttermonk. yes, did verify that is the case. still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the boot order of your drives in your BIOS/UEFI. Since the WD does not have a an OS your server won't start if it "thinks" it is the system drive.

Comment: I have another usb external drive connected to the same server that does not cause boot issues. If its the boot order, wouldnt that cause issues as well? I have moved the connected usbs around and that does not seem to matter. Thanks.

Comment: @ayo try the answer first...

Comment: @Nmath is there a way to do this on a headless server? i will try to do this when I get home. is the only way to connect a monitor and a keyboard to it?

Comment: Thanks @Nmath. I just checked and the boot option is set to the internal hard drive and not to any of the usb devices. Any additional troubleshooting is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would anyone be able to provide me with guidance on this matter? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To enter the bios/UEFI you need a monitor, no way around it. With your sparse information (not much data) I have to assume that your server thinks it needs to start from your WD harddisk (which does not have an OS). So plug in a monitor and change the start sequence.

Comment: @kanehekili not sure if you saw my previous comment. yes, that was what i did and confirmed that the boot priority is set to the internal hdd and not the exfat external hdd

Comment: Strange. In this case an external drive should not interfere with starting your server... Sorry, but something is not as it supposed to be. If your internal hdd is prio 1 and your external WD is not, then something is wrong. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @kanehekili i totally understand. I, too, am dumbfounded. I have tried the exfat drive on both Windows and Linux (Mint) systems and do not encounter any issues during boot up. I dont have another piece of hardware to try installing Ubuntu server to confirm the boot failure that is why I was hoping someone would be able to confirm if there are known issues with Ubuntu server and exfat HDDs. They have escalated and will get back to me. Can anyone with Ubuntu server v20 try booting with an exfat hdd connected? To add, I have also contacted Zotac to see if its something on the hardware side.

Comment: I see this an old question so I'm not sure if this is still an issue but another user had a very similar issue.  Try running `tail -f /var/log/syslog` in an open terminal, connect the drives and see if any output is generated.  That's what I would do if this were my machine.